# PHP/Go socket communication

Tags: php, sockets, go

Im trying to communicate between Go and PHP with a socket. The code im using is:

Go:

```
fmt.Println("Launching server...")
ln, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
conn, _ := ln.Accept()

for {
    message, _ := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Print("Message Received:", string(message))
    conn.Write([]byte("test" +"\n"))

}
```

PHP:

```
$address = gethostbyaddr($ip);
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    if($socket === false){
        echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error());
    }

    $result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $port);
    if ($result === false) {
        echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket));
    } 
    socket_write($socket, "test", 4);
    socket_read($socket, 4);
```

The problem is that the Go server keeps thinking it's receiving something all the time so it prints "Message Recieved:" constantly. If i do if(message!="") it sort of works but the cpu usage is high.

Another problem is that the server doesn't receive "test" unless i comment out the socket_read($socket, 4); in PHP.

Comment: bufio.Reader.Readstring returns an error that you are not checking.

Comment: If i check the error it says "E0F"

Comment: Never ignore errors. Don't create a new `bufio.Reader` each iteration through the loop! Handle `io.EOF`.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString) for `ReadString` says:

> If ReadString encounters an error before finding a delimiter, it returns the data read before the error and the error itself (often io.EOF).

This means that you're getting `io.EOF` (indicating that there's no more data to be read from the connection) and an empty string.

If you want to block on ReadString when no data is available, don't use `bufio` but rather read directly from the connection.

See also: [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn) for `net.Conn`

> Another problem is that the server doesn't receive "test" unless i comment out the socket_read($socket, 4); in PHP.

That's described [here](http://php.net/socket_write), `socket_write` buffers:

> socket_write() does not necessarily write all bytes from the given buffer. [...]

use

```
fflush($socket);
```

after the write.

Comment: Your comment about blocking and `bufio` makes no sense to me. `bufio.ReadString` blocks as requred.